# Can we have a table displayed without applying any inputs

Tags: r

below is the reprex code. The code is fine, but actually as soon as I open the app, I need only 2 rows of the iris table displayed (Like this should be mandatory without any filter and submit button). then as per the filter and submit button the table should be displayed. can we achieve this?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
selectInput("Tic","",choices = c("","ALL",as.character(iris$Species)),selected = NULL)
actionButton("Submit","Submit")
textOutput("Total")
tableOutput("SUMMARY_GENERAL_table")


  data1 <- eventReactive(input$Submit,{
  if(input$Tic == "ALL"){
  table_display  <- iris
  }

  else {
  table_display <- iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$Tic)
  }
})


output$SUMMARY_GENERAL_table <- renderTable(
                data1()
  )


output$Total <- renderText(
  paste0("Sum ",formatC(as.numeric(sum(data1()[(data1()$Species == "setosa"),]$Sepal.Width))))
)

```
````

Answer (score 0):

This should work: I first define `data1` but without requiring to press "Submit". Then, I detail two expressions for the table: one when "Submit" is not clicked and one when "Submit" is clicked.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(DT)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ### Chart A

```{r}
selectInput("Tic","",choices = c("","ALL",as.character(iris$Species)),selected = NULL)
actionButton("Submit","Submit")
textOutput("Total")
tableOutput("SUMMARY_GENERAL_table")

data1 <- reactive({

  if (input$Tic != "ALL"){
    table_display <- iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$Tic)
  }
  else{
    table_display  <- iris
  }

})

output$SUMMARY_GENERAL_table <- renderTable({
  iris
})

observeEvent(input$Submit, {
  output$SUMMARY_GENERAL_table <- renderTable({
    data1()
  })
})


output$Total <- renderText(
  paste0("Sum ",formatC(as.numeric(sum(data1()[(data1()$Species == "setosa"),]$Sepal.Width))))
)

```
````